# How to pass user input value from a PHP page to HTML page using AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a course table in the database which stores course information (i.e. code, name, date and description). Admin is allowed to update the course information. Let's assume that a course information is already in my database and the admin intends to update the course info.

When he heads to the Update page (pls see managemodule.php), my page will show him a dropdown options with a list of courses that are in the database. He will then choose a particular course from the dropdown list and then the course information will be shown (achieved thru' ajax) in different **HTML input fields** (info is output thru. the **placeholder** attr.).

What I want to achieve here is that, admin can update whatever info they want in the **input fields** directly, and when he presses 'update', these data will be sent over and update in my database.

However I failed to do so. I know it's the problem of the ajax code in managemodule.js.
The course table in the database has 4 columns which is **code, name, date and description**

managemodule.php:

```
<form id="moduleform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Module Info Update</h2>
    <p>Please select a module for more information:</p><br />

    <select id="modulelist" name="module" onchange="showModuleInfo(this.value)">
        <option>-- Select a module --</option>
        <option value="CS2102">Database Systems</option>   ***hard coded here for simplicity*****
    </select>

<?php    ****This php part is not updating my course table********
            if(isset($_POST['update']))
            {   
                mysql_query("UPDATE module SET code = '".$_POST['update_moduleCode']."' ");
            }
?>


    <div id="moduleinfo"><b><-- Module info will be listed here --></b></div>   
</form>
```

managemodule.js:

```
function showModuleInfo(str)
{
    if (str == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("moduleinfo").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("moduleinfo").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","moduleinfo.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

moduleinfo.php

```
    session_start();

    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM module WHERE code = '".$q."'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<input type="text" name="update_moduleCode" placeholder="Module Code" value="'.$row['code'].'" required />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="update_moduleTitle" placeholder="Module Name" value="'.$row['name'].'" required />';
        echo '<textarea name="update_moduleDescription" rows="14" placeholder="Module Description" required></textarea><br />';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="update" class="next action-button" value="Update" />'; 

*****I guess this 'Update' button is not passing the user input to my managemodule.php
    }
```

The php part in managemodule.php above is not working (means it doesnt update my course table). I guess it is because the 'Update' button is not passing user input to managemodule.php. I used **$_POST['update_moduleCode']** wanted to get the value from moduleinfo.php but I didnt manage to get.

So how am I supposed to pass the input from moduleinfo.php to managemodule.php

Comment: What are the actual file names and are these all three separate files or did you cut and paste certain parts from the same file

Comment: Let me be more clear:  Is this "HTML" page actually a PHP file with HTML code mixed with PHP or is it actually an HTML file like `index.html` or something

Comment: @Deryck Sorry I should have made it clear. It's a PHP file actually with HTML codes in it. All these 3 are separate files.

Comment: While I continue writing this monologue, go ahead and remove `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"` from your `<form>` and see what happens when you change the module again.

Comment: @Deryck I have removed that line but still it didnt work. The reason I put it is because I will do some user input validation which I didnt include the code here. But will it actually be the reason which cause the issue?

Comment: @Deryck Hey sorry just want to say it works now! I noticed that after removed that line, I can see user input in my URL, and I found out that I should change `xmlhttp.open("GET","moduleinfo.php?q="+str,true)` to POST instead and it just worked :) Thank you for pointing me out.

Comment: Glad it all worked out!

Comment: @Deryck I tested out, actually changing from GET to POST in `xmlhttp.open("GET","moduleinfo.php?q="+str,true)` didnt work :( User input still shows up in URL. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Because you have `"?q="+str` and don't need it.  You put `str` inside of `send()` if you're using `POST`  -  so your new code will be `xmlhttp.open("POST", "moduleinfo.php", true); xmlhttp.send(str);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that in moduleinfo.php file your update button is doing nothing when you click it. That's because it is not inside a HTML form and there is nothing binded to the onclick event. You should either create a function like showModuleInfo() but POSTing the data to a separate PHP file (that will update the database) or create a HTML form in moduleinfo.php that POST data to managemodule.php.

Despite that, I have some considerations about your code:

**PHP extension mysql is deprecated**

According to PHP documentation ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php ) this extension is deprecated. You should use mysqli or pdo_mysql instead.

**Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection**

Note that you are using a information from $_GET directly into a MySQL query.

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM module WHERE code = '".$q."'");
```

It makes your code vulnerable to a kind of attack named SQL injection. Instead, you should treat variables got from $_POST and $_GET with mysqli_real_escape_string ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php ) or using PDO prepared statements ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php ).

**You are mixing your business logic with the view (HTML code)**

You are writing both the business logic code and the view code (HTML) in the same file. It makes your application very hard to maintain. You should have a look at some design patterns, starting with MVC (Model-View-Controller).

**You are writing pure javascript code**

Well, that's not exactly a bad thing. But you should consider that there are inconsistencies between browsers and sometimes, writing pure javascript code, your code may work in a browser but not in another. You should consider taking a look in the available javascript frameworks (I recommend jQuery), they take care of these inconsistencies and also have a lot of ready functionality.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! I have learnt a lot :)

Comment: A quick question sir. Do you know what is the reason that I couldnt pass any variable in `moduleinfo.php` to `managemodule.php`? For instance, if I do `$_SESSION['q'] = $q`, even if I called `$_SESSION['q']` in managemodule.php, I wasnt able to get any values. Any idea?

Comment: Are you calling session_start() in both moduleinfo.php and managemodule.php? Note that this function should be called in the very top of the file, before any content is sent to the client.